# Using InternetConnect with IP-address fails (error 12029)

Tags: c++, wininet

Here i have a snippet that doesn't work when i'am using IP address. But in MSDN it says that parameter could be dotted-decimal IP address, so it must work clearly. What is wrong? Thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"        
        #include <windows.h>
        #include <wininet.h>
        #include <tchar.h>
        #include <iostream>        
        #pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")
        using namespace std;

        int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
        {
            char szServer[] = "127.0.0.1";
            char szUrl[] = "/test/upload.php";
            char Data[] = "text123";
            char szHdrs[] =    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x";   
            char szTead[] =    "--AaB03x\r\n"
                               "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n"
                               "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"
                                "\r\n";
            char szTail[] =     "\r\n"
                                "--AaB03x--\r\n";
            char szUserAgent[] = "MyUA";
            char *szTypes[] = {"*/*", NULL};
            HINTERNET hIOpen = InternetOpenA(szUserAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
            if(!hIOpen)
            {
                printf("InternetOpenA Error\n");
            }
            HINTERNET hIConnect = InternetConnectA(hIOpen, szServer, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
            if(!hIConnect)
            {
                printf("InternetConnectA Error\n");
            }
            HINTERNET hHttpOpReq = HttpOpenRequestA(hIConnect, "POST", szUrl, NULL, NULL, (LPCSTR *)szTypes, 0, 1);
            if(!hHttpOpReq)
            {
                printf("HttpOpenRequestA Error\n");
            }
            BOOL bHttpSendReq = HttpSendRequestA(hHttpOpReq, szHdrs, strlen(szHdrs), Data, strlen(Data));
            if (!bHttpSendReq)
            {   int Error = GetLastError();
                printf("HttpSendRequest Error %d\n", Error);
            }


            system("pause");
            return 0;

        }
```

There is nothing more i can add, actually about this issue. I'am using Windows 7 x64 Ultimate and VS2008.

Now i checked this .exe on other XP and Seven machines. Looks like it works, but not on my machine. Maybe the problem is (out there) somewhere else.

Comment: So it works is you use "localhost" instead?

Comment: Yes, and it's strange. The problem is i need to use IP-address.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it maybe being a firewall or proxy issue. I assume you have the same problem with "real-world" servers, so it can't be the web server refusing connections.

Answer (score 0):

Three hints:

1. Add following flags to your internetconnect:

   INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE
2. Also add http to your reqest:

   char szServer[] = "http://127.0.0.1";
3. You might also try with INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT instead of INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG

in my code base I have a work around for a 12029 error, but it happens only when connection is lost during file downloading - to fix it I must fully close all WinInet handles and retry download.